# Octave display error, Really small fonts

Tags: octave

I've installed Octave 4.2.0 on Ubuntu 16.04:

```
wget ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/octave/octave-4.2.0.tar.gz
tar xf octave-4.2.0.tar.gz
rm octave-4.2.0.tar.gz
cd octave-4.2.0/
./configure
make -j8
sudo make install
```

However there is a graphical bug in my Octave terminal:

[image: screenshot of issue]

The rows in terminal are stupidly small to see the present code.

How can I get rid of this bug?

Comment: Do you really need 4.2.0? 4.0 is available from the 16.04 repository

Comment: Yes I need it due to geometry package that requires "Dependencies:  Octave (>= 4.0.1)". I'm not sure it is compatible with Octave 4.0

Comment: I built it myself in a 16.04 VM and could not reproduce the issue - sometimes this kind of thing is specific to particular graphics hardware / drivers

Comment: I downgraded to Octave 4.0.1 and the rows are normal.

Answer (score 6):

I fixed it by changing the font from Courier to another type. In my case, I changed it to Andale Mono. I have Octave version 4.2.2, and my Ubuntu is 16.04 LTS.

[image]